# Direct3D 3D graphics over 2D sprites

Tags: directx, overlay, direct3d, point, sprite

In a Direct3D application I'm working on I need to render a particle system (point sprites) over 2D sprite images. The 2D sprites are drawn using an LPD3DXSPRITE object with the Draw method. The particles are being draw in a 3D perspective and I need them to be overlayed on top of the 2D sprites. My problem is that the background sprite I'm rendering for the background of the game is covering the point sprites in the 3D perspective. If I remove the background image I can see the point sprites.

How can I go about having the point sprites on top of the background image? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off z writing (ZWRITEENABLE assuming you are using D3D9) draw the sprite.  Then draw your particle system as normal (which may or may not involve enabling Z writing) and it will draw on top of the sprite.

Comment: that wasn't the problem in this case. When I called the Begin method of D3DXSPRITE I didn't pass it the parameter that puts the sprite in object space. Changing this allowed me to use the sprite how I needed to.